# entity framework scaffold on a npgsql database- in .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, npgsql

Trying to scaffold a NPGSQL database(containing data from osm) to an entityFramework model, which works fine when i do it on a .NetCore project using these dependencies:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Npgsql.EntityFramework.Postgresql
Npgsql.EntityFramework.Postgresql.NetTopologySuite
```

and this command line:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Host=localhost;Database=osm;Username=[yourUserName];Password=[YourPassword]" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o model -f
```

However i get an error when i try to do the same in a .netFrameworkProject on the command line step:

```
[projectPath]\FWCL.OSM\obj\FWCL.OSM.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets(4,5): error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph that involves the target "GetEFProjectMetadata". [[projectPath]\FWCL.OSM\FWCL.OSM.csproj]
Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.
```

Is it not possible to use a npgsql scaffold for .NetFramework target? It seems weird that the use of npgsql would be limited to .NetCore .

To clarify, i am getting this error in an empty project which i just created and installed the five dependencies above.

Comment: According to the error message, the problem isn't with you targeting .NET Framework, it's with the old-style csproj. Try using a new-style SDK csproj: this is the modern csproj type used by .NET Core, but you can still set <TargetFramework> to e.g. `net4.8`. This should make the tools work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Visual Studio on Windows, [this](https://medium.com/@RobertKhou/getting-started-with-entity-framework-core-postgresql-c6fa09681624) might help. This is what worked for me after I installed all the required Nuget packages.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Host=localhost;Database=mydatabase;Username=myuser;Password=mypassword" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o Models
```

I ran the above command from Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Package Manager Console and it generated the dbcontext and all models into the Models folder.

Hope this helps!